# Archive attempt in Xcode 11.4 result in error: “The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.”

Tags: xcode

1) I registered a brand new identifier in Apple Developer - org.cogswatch.Complaints14.

2) I set the bundle ID of my new app in applestoreconnect to org.cogswatch.Complaints14.

3) I set my bundle identifier in Xcode to org.cogswatch.Complaints14

4) I attempted to archive / distribute in Xcode 11.4 and got:
App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90129: “The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.”

5) Sanity check - I changed the bundle ID in Xcode to org.cogswatch.Complaints14a and still got:
App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90129: “The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.”

6) Another sanity check - I removed the app in appstoreconnect, and tried another distribute in Xcode and got:
App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-4241: “App is Removed or Deleted. Apps can’t be validated or submitted while they’re removed or deleted.” at SoftwareAssets

7) I Restored the app in appstoreconnect and tried again to distribute in Xcode and got:
App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90129: “The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.”

Comment: Are you sure you archived the right target?

Comment: Have you resolved such a problem?